# Change background using database value MVC 3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am creating a website using MVC 3 ASP.Net. I want to know how to change the background colour of a div tag which is set in my master layout page. This will change dependent on my database value.

An example of this is: First get the database value in my controller then render it in the view page. The colour is set in a separate css file.

Does anyone have any ideas or examples of how I can do this?

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: tell us something more about how the value is and describe some more

Comment: I have a product in a product table i.e product id and product name. What i want is if a certain product is clicked on, the colour of the background changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller action**

You can set a property on the `ViewBag` to the colour from your database.

```
ViewBag.DivColour = "redClass";
```

**View**

Then on your view use the property.

```
<div class="@ViewBag.DivColour">I'm coloured!</div>
```

**CSS**

Assuming you have something in your CSS like:

```
.redClass {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color on click event by css

```
.product:focus{
background:#ddd;

}
```

or by jQuery

```
$(this).css("background","#ddd");
```